# A start job is running for eth0

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, devices, ethernet, dhcpcd

I am using a new installation of Arch Linux and whenever I boot my system I have to wait for 90 seconds as there is a start job running for my network interfaces.

I installed Arch yesterday and whenever I do `ip a` I get that ethernet interfaces is in `DOWN` state. I used a wired usb tether to complete the whole installation. I just want to remove that start job process while starting. I saw a solution somewhere in Arch community that I have to disable my interface using:

```
# systemctl disable dhcpcd@interface_name
```

I haven't done that yet. My  question is if I disable that interface will that cause any problems in future? I am not using any LAN connections now. Will that cause any problems if in future I want to use a LAN or some kind of ethernet connection?

Output of `uname -a`:

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ uname -a
Linux brightprogrammer 4.19.26-1-lts #1 SMP Wed Feb 27 16:06:52 CET 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:fa:5b:5b:9e:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:b8:6d:c9:57:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.201/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 2153sec preferred_lft 2153sec
    inet6 2405:205:a061:4977:348c:2fe2:102:47ac/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::614a:460c:ff14:9caa/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `find /etc/systemd`:

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ find /etc/systemd
/etc/systemd
/etc/systemd/journald.conf
/etc/systemd/coredump.conf
/etc/systemd/sleep.conf[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ systemd-analyze
```

Startup finished in 5.369s (firmware) + 1.785s (loader) + 5.214s (kernel) + 1min 33.882s (userspace) = 1min 46.252s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 33.882s in userspace

```
/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf
/etc/systemd/system.conf
/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
/etc/systemd/journal-upload.conf
/etc/systemd/networkd.conf
/etc/systemd/system
/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants
/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants
/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@eth0.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wicd.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@wlp2s0.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/remote-fs.target
/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants
/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.wicd.daemon.service
/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
/etc/systemd/user
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/p11-kit-server.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/pipewire.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/dirmngr.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-extra.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-browser.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-ssh.socket
/etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/pulseaudio.socket
/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants
/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/xdg-user-dirs-update.service
/etc/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/network
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

Output of `systemd-analyze` :

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.369s (firmware) + 1.785s (loader) + 5.214s (kernel) + 1min 33.882s (userspace) = 1min 46.252s
graphical.target reached after 1min 33.882s in userspace
```

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-analyze` :

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.

graphical.target @1min 33.882s
└─gdm.service @1min 33.615s +265ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 33.503s +110ms
    └─network.target @1min 33.501s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @15.761s +638ms
        └─basic.target @11.036s
          └─sockets.target @11.036s
            └─dbus.socket @11.036s
              └─sysinit.target @11.028s
                └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @14.008s >
                  └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @14.006s
                    └─system.slice @2.915s
                      └─-.slice @2.915s
```

Output of `systemd-analyze blame` :

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ systemd-analyze blame
         11.692s dhcpcd@wlp2s0.service
         11.692s dhcpcd@wlp2s0.service
          6.472s lvm2-monitor.service
          4.616s wicd.service
          3.222s systemd-journal-flush.service
          3.188s NetworkManager.service
          2.719s bluetooth.service
          2.711s systemd-logind.service
          1.395s systemd-sysusers.service
          1.216s systemd-udevd.service
          1.213s ldconfig.service
           981ms udisks2.service
           971ms polkit.service
           649ms user@120.service
           638ms wpa_supplicant.service
           600ms systemd-modules-load.service
           526ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           501ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           493ms upower.service
           487ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           464ms systemd-journald.service
           371ms systemd-journal-catalog-update.service
           338ms systemd-sysctl.service
           268ms colord.service
           265ms gdm.service
           260ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           238ms dev-sda2.swap
           236ms accounts-daemon.service
           142ms systemd-random-seed.service
           135ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           110ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            91ms user@1000.service
            81ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            54ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            48ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            35ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            28ms dev-hugepages.mount
            26ms user-runtime-dir@120.service
            25ms sys-kernel-config.mount
            16ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
            15ms dev-mqueue.mount
             9ms rtkit-daemon.service
             6ms systemd-update-done.service
             4ms systemd-rfkill.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms tmp.mount
```

Output of `systemctl status dhcpcd@eth0.service` and `dhcpcd@enp1s0f1` :

```
[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd@eth0.service
● dhcpcd@eth0.service - dhcpcd on eth0
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service; enabled; vendor pre>
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 05 09:42:42 brightprogrammer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dhcpcd on eth0.
Mar 05 09:42:42 brightprogrammer systemd[1]: dhcpcd@eth0.service: Job dhcpcd@eth0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

[siddharth@brightprogrammer ~]$ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd@enp1s0f1.service
● dhcpcd@enp1s0f1.service - dhcpcd on enp1s0f1
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service; disabled; vendor pr>
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I recently disabled enp1s0f1. That might be the reason it is disabled.

I can also provide the output of `journalctl -xe` but that is very large! Also I suspect that `dhcpcd` is somehow confused between `eth0` and my `enp1s0f1`

Comment: Welcome , also you need to remove Wicd because you have NetworkManager already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's very likely the problem you're seeing is with the `dhcpcd@eth0.service` that's configured on your system. So my recommendation would be to disable it, hopefully that's enough to make that timeout during boot disappear:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd@eth0
```

I'll go over the evidence to support that claim. There's more troubleshooting that can be done here, I'll suggest some more steps (in case you want to look further, or troubleshoot similar issues in the future.)

The main evidence of the issue is the message on output of `systemctl status dhcpcd@eth0` which says:

```
Mar 05 09:42:42 brightprogrammer systemd[1]: dhcpcd@eth0.service: Job dhcpcd@eth0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Failed with result "dependency" means, in this case, it was waiting for something else, that failed. This service will have a dependency on `eth0.device` and this device will not appear, so that's the probable source of the timeout. You can take a look at `systemctl status eth0.device` to see if anything else shows up, it's possible it will (but then, it's possible it won't.)

Like you mentioned in your question, there's probably a mix up between `eth0` and the actual device name of `enp1s0f1` in your system. systemd (more specifically udevd) will rename network interfaces to give them a consistent name and this typically happens very early at boot (sometimes even before systemd comes up), so systemd will not really see the `eth0` name anymore.

If you want to enable DHCP on that interface in the future, enable `dhcpcd@enp1s0f1` instead.

The output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` supports the hypothesis of timeout on that `dhcpcd@eth0` service, which you can see from these two steps:

```
└─network.target @1min 33.501s    
  └─wpa_supplicant.service @15.761s +638ms
```

The times after `@` are the clock times right after boot. The `wpa_supplicant` service came up 13s after systemd started, but `network.target` was only reached at 1m33s (roughly the 90s you talk about.)

You would probably had seen `dhcpcd@eth0` here more explicitly, but the unit actually went into the "loaded"/"inactive" state, rather than "failed", so that's probably why it isn't listed prominently here (and in `systemd-analyze blame`), which would have helped point it out as the culprit.

Finally, one step that's usually a great start when troubleshooting systemd boot issues is to start by looking at the bare `systemctl status` output, which will tell you whether the system is in "degraded" state, which indicates that something failed during boot. You want to ensure the system status will be "running", so investigating those failures will typically uncover issues such as timeouts, etc.

You can proceed the investigation from that point by looking at output of `systemctl`, which will list all active units and their status, if you see problems there, look further by investigating specific units (with `systemctl status <unit>` or `journalctl -u <unit>`.) Command `systemctl --state=failed` is also useful to show only the failed units.

Finally, checking the journal is really good to make correlations. Command `journalctl -b` shows the journal since the system booted, so it's great to look into issues during boot. As mentioned before, `journalctl -u <unit>` is useful to investigate logs for a single unit.

Hopefully these tips will be helpful to you in digging deeper and understanding what is happening in your system. Also hoping that disabling that `dhcpcd@eth0` is enough to solve the boot delay you're experiencing.

Comment: when I do `systemctl status eth0.device`, It says : `Loaded : loaded` and `Active : inactive (dead)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue, by re-enabling the systemd unit for the profile specified (eth0).

```
netctl reenable eth0
```

Now the 90 second bootup is cleared after a reboot.

Comment: I disabled netctl and dhcpcd and I am using NM only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you don't have configured network yet (typical after fresh installation) but system trying to start whole network stuff.
Untill the net config will be properly established just disable the dependency of systemd user sessions and the network daemons.

**From: /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-user-sessions.service**

**Section: [Unit]**

**Line: After=....**

**remove network.target** then execute systemctl daemon-reload